# Pasing the time from excel to Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date, time

[image]I want to pass the the time from an excel file it is in `format 12:45:00 PM` but when i read the file in my pythons code it is transformed to `00:45:00`. How i can stop python from converting my time column to its own date I am using the following code.

```
df2_all_rows['Time_conv'] =  pd.to_datetime(df2_all_rows['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
df2_all_rows['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df2_all_rows['Time_conv'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.hour
```

The aim is to get both the hours and to separate a column having seperate AM and PM with the associated times

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this-

```
>>> d='12:45:00 PM'
>>> pd.to_datetime(d).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
'12:45:00'
```

And if you'll provide an example for the dataset it self we'll be able to answer it more properly on your specific case (:

Comment: I have added a picture now of what i am seeing at my python code. I guess its something of exporting from excel to python as i have changed the times in my excel file and i dont want python to change it when i am exporting the file

Comment: @gmm005 can you add it in the text so I'll be able to paste it easily in the console?

Comment: I am getting this in my python                                                                   
          (  UNIX Time Date  Time
 1541203200 2018-11-03 00:00:00)                                                                     i have got this in excel   which i also want in my python                                                                       
  ((1422316800 1/27/2015 12:00:00 AM
   1422316800       1/27/2015          12:15:00 AM))
1422316800 1/27/2015 12:30:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

Using `pd.read_csv('filename', parse_dates=['column_name_containing_time'])` to read the excel file will preserve the time in the format that you require i.e. `12:45:00 PM`
[Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vp1T.png)

`pd.read_csv('./file.csv',parse_dates=['TIME'])
          TIME NAME
0  13:45:00 PM   xx
1  01:40:47 AM   zz`

Comment: it did work for me, I have edited the post with the excel file content and the result i obtained

Comment: i am using xlsx  type not csv

Comment: In that case, you can either save your file as .csv and try the aforementioned or use `pd.read_excel('./somefile.xlsx')`.It worked for me.

Comment: i am working with multiple excel sheets that is not the solution